# How to scale MDL spinner?

Tags: css, material-design-lite

It there any way to scale MDL spinner? I tried to change it's `widht` and `height` properties, but it becomes thiner. Take a look:

**CSS**

```
width: 150px; 
height: 150px
```

**Result**

[image]

Comment: Have you tried: `transform: scale(1.5);` for example?

Comment: Yes. It brings to unexpected behaviour.

Comment: What is the desired outcome?

Comment: Just scale it. Keep proportions, but just make it bigger.

Comment: The borders are fixed, so naturally, they would look "thinner" if the container is bigger. You can change the `border-width` value for `.mdl-spinner__circle` which is `3px` by default, If I'm not wrong.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Found it.

You need to set new properties.

**CSS**

```
.mdl-spinner {
  width: 28px;
  height: 28px;
}

.mdl-spinner__circle {
  border-width: 3px;
}
```

And change them in proportion 28/3. Let's say, if you want to make it 3 times bigger, your code will look like:

**CSS**

```
.mdl-spinner {
  width: 84px;
  height: 84px;
}

.mdl-spinner__circle {
  border-width: 9px;
}
```

Be careful! It does affect on your FPS if scaled more than in 10 times.

Answer (score -1):

I had to use `!important`.

```css
.mdl-spinner {
  width: 64px !important;
  height: 64px !important;
}

.mdl-spinner__circle {
  border-width: 6px !important;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- Material Design Lite -->
    <script src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.indigo-pink.min.css">
    <!-- Material Design icon font -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- MDL Spinner Component -->
    <div class="mdl-spinner mdl-js-spinner is-active"></div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's totally a problem of code snippets. You won't get it in a local environment you override styles after including MDL stylesheet. Works fine on CodePen without `!important` https://codepen.io/dukeimg/pen/OmWzdG